# Enabling and using Role Management in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC. I setup a basic MVC5 Web Application with authentication.
I observed that when I run the program the first time, it has register and login.
So i registered and login but found no means to setup role management, because I thought i will find menu there like MANAGE ROLES.
How am i going to enable, create, and use the role management?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks God I found what I am looking for at this awesome website 
http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx
Thanks to the author John Atten

Comment: Brilliant article

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you posted here. John (sadly) closed comments on that blog. I followed it and after spending a whole day on it, I found it just doesn't work as-published. The biggest problem I saw is that you will likely get a "no key defined" error on SelectRoleEditorViewModel. This happened when I tried to scaffold an empty view as well as when I tried to create a new migration against the database.

If anyone has comments, let's use this forum to discuss them! My solution is now working but I had to make a number of tweaks in order to get it to the finish line...